# Realtime changing graph and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataframe (df) with 2000 rows.

```
          from        close   min     max   
0       1607403960  1.21145 1.21145 1.21145 
1       1607404020  1.21145 1.21149 1.21145 
2       1607404080  1.21149 1.21155 1.21149 
3       1607404140  1.21155 1.21154 1.21154 
4       1607404200  1.21154 1.21154 1.21153 
...        ...        ...     ...     ...
1995    1607523660  1.21167 1.21150 1.21147 
1996    1607523720  1.21150 1.21144 1.21144 
1997    1607523780  1.21144 1.21129 1.21126 
1998    1607523840  1.21129 1.21141 1.21129 
1999    1607523900  1.21141 1.21149 1.21141
```

Then, I am plotting this in a graph:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Plot')
plt.plot(df['close'])
plt.xlabel('x axis', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('y axis', fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

I am also getting realtime data with the default dictionary format, which has more categories. For example:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {1607527380: {'active_id': 1, 'size': 60, 'at': 1607527422003075951, 'from': 1607527380, 'close': 1.607380, 'min': 1.527380, 'max': 1.7380}})
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {1607527380: {'active_id': 1, 'size': 60, 'at': 1607527422003075951, 'from': 1607527380, 'close': 1.607380, 'min': 1.527380, 'max': 1.7380}})
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {1607527380: {'active_id': 1, 'size': 60, 'at': 1607527422003075951, 'from': 1607527380, 'close': 1.607380, 'min': 1.527380, 'max': 1.7380}})
```

I want to append this data to my previous df in realtime. How can I do this? How do I convert this format into a pandas dataframe? And then I was thinking about using FuncAnimation function from matplotlib in order to get a dynamic graph. Do you think this is the best way to do this? I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create pd.DataFrames with dictionaries. These can then be filtered by column names and the obtained DataFrames be merged. See the code below:

```
d1 = {
    1607527380: {
        "active_id": 1,
        "size": 60,
        "at": 1607527422003075951,
        "from": 1607527380,
        "close": 1.607380,
        "min": 1.527380,
        "max": 1.7380,
    }
}

d2 = {
    1607527380: {
        "active_id": 1,
        "size": 60,
        "at": 1607527422003075951,
        "from": 1607527380,
        "close": 1.607380,
        "min": 1.527380,
        "max": 1.7380,
    }
}


import pandas as pd

full_df = pd.DataFrame()
for D in (d1, d2):
    #you can create pd.DataFrames from dict(),  .T is used to flip the axis
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(D).T
    #by indexing, you can filter out columns
    reduced_df = new_df[["from", "close", "min", "max"]]
    # pd.concat() combines both dataframes
    full_df = pd.concat([full_df, reduced_df], ignore_index=True)

print(full_df)

"""
           from    close      min    max
0  1.607527e+09  1.60738  1.52738  1.738
1  1.607527e+09  1.60738  1.52738  1.738
"""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, what if I don't have the dictionaries with names (d1, d2,...)? Because I'm getting them in realtime in the format I specified above (defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, ...). And how can I append the data from full_df to the original df (the one with 2000 rows) in realtime? That is, when I get a new dictionary, I want to append this to df. Should I use pd.concat() too?